# Debug console not blocked for std input required by library function

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio-2017, openssl

Every **code works fine. Debugging with visual studio is problem**.

I'm making Linux server using openSSL library with c++11.

The server runs on CentOS in VMware. (Will move to Azure when completed)

I work on Visual studio 2017, cross-compile linked with that CentOS.

When I call

```
int SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *file, int type);
```

this funcntion in ssl library, it opens private key file, require me password on standard input, showing up message on standard out and wait for my input.

But if I run on Visual studio debug mode, it just passes away.

It works fine when I use .out file on CentOS, and that '.out' file is compiled by visual studio for debugging.

It's not a path problem. '.crt' file opens well and only '.key' file in the same folder not opens well.

these are the code where problem occur.
SslUtil, ExceptionSslUtil class is in my own code. but the other all functions and structures in this code are in ssl library.

```
void SslUtil::InitAsServer(const char* pathCert, const char* pathKey) {
    amIServer = true;
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
    meth = SSLv23_server_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);

    if (!ctx)
        throw ExceptionSslUtil("ctx create error");
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, pathCert, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
        throw ExceptionSslUtil("cert file open error");
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file( ctx, pathKey, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)// here's the problem.
        throw ExceptionSslUtil("private key file open error");
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx))
        throw ExceptionSslUtil("Private key does not match the certificate public keyn");                                                                                                                                       
    return;
}
```

SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file function not blocked for input, just returning minus value. It has to wait for input but not.

I have no idea what's happening there.
It worked previously,

but when I change original main(argc, argv) function into mainSslEpoll(argc, argv) and make it called by other main function, this problem happen... why?
The following is my new main function.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string str;
    while (true) {
        cout << "select mode" << endl;
        cout << "\t" << "0:SSL + Epoll server" << endl;
        cout << "\t" << "1:SSL server" << endl;
        cout << "\t" << "2:SSL client" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        if (str[0] == '0') return mainSslEpoll(argc, argv);
        if (str[0] == '1') return mainSslServer(argc, argv);
        if (str[0] == '2') return mainSslClient(argc, argv);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you checked access permissions of file '.key' ?

Comment: @Fi Ras It has been less than a week to make '.key' file. and I made it again but not worked.